# Register a type with primitive-arguments constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I have a class that has in its constructor some primitive type arguments, such as string etc.

How should I register the type with unity container?

```
public LoginManager(
  IRegionManager regionManager, 
  IEventAggregator eventAggregator, 
  string mainRegionName, 
  Uri login, 
  Uri target)
  {
    this.regionManager = regionManager;
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.mainRegionName = mainRegionName;
    this.login = login;
    this.target = target;
  }
}
```

**Update**:
Remeber that the `IRegionManager` and the `IEventAggregator` are known types to the Prism UnityBootstrapper which is the container wrapper in my case. Do I have to re-register them?? I want to keep the type-registration as simple as possible.

Would this be considered a bad habit? Any better alternatives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to prevent to have a class design that has primitive or hard to resolve types in the constructor. As you have already seen from Tavares' answer, you're configuration gets very brittle (*update: Tavares seems to have removed his answer for reasons that are not clear to me*). You loose compile time support, and every change to that constructor would make you change your DI configuration.

There are multiple ways to change your design to prevent this. Which one is applicable for you is up to you, but here are a few ideas:

**Option 1: Use an immutable configuration DTO:**

```
private sealed class LoginManagerConfiguration
{
    public Uri Login { get; private set; }
    public Uri Target { get; private set; }
    public string MainRegionName { get; private set; }

    public LoginManagerConfiguration(Uri login, Uri target, string mainRegionName)
    {
        this.Login = login;
        this.Target = target;
        this.MainRegionName = mainRegionName;
    }
}
```

Now you can let your `LoginManager` take a dependency on `LoginManagerConfiguration`:

```
public LoginManager(IRegionManager regionManager,
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
    LoginManagerConfiguration configuration)
{
    ...
}
```

The `LoginManagerConfiguration` can simply be registered like this:

```
container.RegisterInstance<LoginManagerConfiguration>(
    new LoginManagerConfiguration(
        login: new Uri("Login"),
        target: new Uri("Target"),
        mainRegionName: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainRegion"]));
```

It might be tempting to specify an application-wide configuration object instead of this type-specific DTO, but that's a trap. Such application-wide configuration object is the configuration equivalent of the Service Locator anti-pattern. It becomes unclear what configuration values a type requires, and makes classes harder to test.

**Option 2: Derive from that class**

Another option is to derive from that class, just for the purpose of DI configuration. This is especially useful when you can't change the class signature (i.e. when it's a third-party component):

```
private sealed class DILoginManager : LoginManager
{
    DILoginManager(IRegionManager regionManager,
        IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        : base(regionManager, eventAggregator,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainRegion"],
            new Uri("Login"),
            new Uri("Target"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Define this class close to the composition root of your application. This class becomes an implementation detail of your DI configuration. Registration of your type will now be very simple:

```
container.RegisterType<ILoginManager, DILoginManager>();
```

Be very careful though with calls that lazy load configuration values, such as `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainRegion"]`. This could easily lead to situations where configuration errors are not caught during application startup, which really is preferable.

**Option 3: Use a factory delegate**

The last option I would like to present is a factory. This will look much like Traveses' answer, but is more type-safe:

```
var mainRegion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainRegion"];

container.Register<ILoginManager>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
{
    return new LoginManager(
        c.Resolve<IRegionManager>(),
        c.Resolve<IEventAggregator>(),
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainRegion"],
        new Uri("Login"),
        new Uri("Target"));
}));
```

Comment: For the InjectionFactory approach, you can also register a type Func<Uri, Uri, String, ILoginManager> for with you associate a InjectionFactory that accepts those parameters and returns an ILoginManager, like this: new InjectionFactory(c => (login, target, mainRegionName) => c.Resolve<ILoginManager>(new ParameterOverride("mainRegionName", mainRegionName), new ParameterOverride("login", login), new ParameterOverride("target", target)))).  By doing the resolve this way you remain flexible in your constructor for dependencies and would only have to change it for primitive parameter changes.

Comment: Forgot to add: usage would be that you would accept a Func<Uri, Uri, String, ILoginManager> as your dependency and pass in those parameters to the function, which would yield the ILoginManager. If these are settings, I would stick with Steven's approach, but if they are runtime values that could change in certain contexts, you might need to do something like this.

Comment: @Anderson Imes: I agree that using a factory for `ILoginManager` instances, because that is what you're actually doing, is a useful approach when the values change during runtime and are determined by the consumers. Instead of registering an `Func<Uri, Uri, string, ILoginManager>` I would rather register an `ILoginManagerFactory`. This communicates clearly what you are injecting.

Comment: agreed. That's definitely the right approach. Normally I register both and the `ILoginManagerFactory` consumes the `Func<Uri, Uri, string, ILoginManager>` and everything else consumes `ILoginManagerFactory`. This way I avoid the ILoginManagerFactory knowing too much about my IoC container, but the constructor for my LoginManager implementation can still be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a bad habit. It is a perfectly valid scenario. It's been few years since I moved on from Unity but from the top of my head with it you have to explicitly point to the constructor you want and enumerate all parameters and for the primitive ones do `new ResolvedParameter("your value")`.

Also I noticed you have a `Type` parameter there. Be cautious with Unity as it has a... very surprising way of handling those. I have a blogpost detailing that [here](http://kozmic.pl/2008/12/03/unity-framework-and-the-principle-of-the-least-surprise/).

Comment: dziękuję. Please take a look at my updated question. I would appreciate if you could provide an example of my particular case. BTW, where is *the top of my head*? I think it's called heap?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly use ResolvedParameter for primitives in the vast majority of cases.