# Resolving a specific constructor parameter in various types using Unity

Tags: .net, unity-container

Let's say I have the following classes.

```
public class Service1
{
   public Service1(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2, string myAppSetting)
   {
   }
}

public class Service2
{
   public Service2(DependencyA dependency1, ..., DependencyD dependency4, string myAppSetting)
   {
   }
}
```

Unity container is used to populate the constructor parameters through dependency injection; container.Resolve(..) methods are never called directly.

The above classes have various parameters but the last parameter `string myAppSetting` is always the same. Is there a way to configure the Unity container to always resolve a parameter with a specific primitive type and name to a specific value in different classes?

I know that you can register injection constructors for every type which seems brittle to me. The other way might be wrapping the string parameter in a custom class. But I was wondering if there is a way to do with specific primitive type constructor parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a interface to wrap my `AppSettings`. This allows me to inject application settings into my types.

**IAppSettings**

```
public interface IAppSettings {
    string MySetting { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**UnityConfig**

```
container.RegisterInstance<IAppSettings>(AppSettings.Current);
container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>();
container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>();
```

**Service1**

```
public class Service1
{
    public Service1(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2, IAppSettings appSettings)
    {
        var mySetting = appSettings.MySetting;
    }
}
```

Here are some options for your primitive parameters: [Register a type with primitive-arguments constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010088/register-a-type-with-primitive-arguments-constructor)

Comment: It does sound like the best work-around is to wrap all the primitive parameters in a class/interface.

Comment: You'll need to eventually resolve those primitives. So you'll want some kind of builder class for your parameter lists to keep your Unity config _less brittle_ -- which you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get Unity to resolve *all* `string` parameters named "myAppSettings" for any class.  But, you can get it to resolve parameters by name for particular classes.  Something like:

```
Container.RegisterType<Service2, Service2>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                    new ResolvedParameter<string>(), 
                        "myAppSetting"));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more like "new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<DependencyA>(), ResolvedParameter<DependencyB>(), ResolvedParameter<DependencyC>(), ResolvedParameter<DependencyD>(), "myAppSettingValue"));"? My problem with this is if you ever add or remove an injected dependency, that code would break.